# Is it possible to recover Visual Studio 2010 syntax color settings that weren't exported?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I put an SSD in my machine and started over with a fresh OS.  I forgot to export my Visual Studio color scheme first.  I still have the old spinning hard drive in an enclosure.  If I run VS off the old drive, it doesn't show my old colors, so I can't export them.  Is there any way to grab the color settings out of the Visual Studio install directory on the old drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in your user's documents folder on the old hard drive. Visual Studio saves its settings in the current user's `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings` folder. You should be able to import the color settings from the file there.